# Python, comparing two files

Tags: python

Suppose I have two (huge) files. One contains a list of words. Another contains a list of words followed by some numbers; i.e., the format is like this:

**file 1:**

```
word1

word2

 ...
```

**file 2:**

```
word1 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5.....n500


word2 n1 n2 n4 n5 .... n500


 ...
```

Using Python 3, what is the most efficient way of overlapping the files and extracting from file 2 only those lines that contain words also occurring in file 1?  Creating a dictionary for file 2 and then going over it and checking membership using the words from file 1 is very slow.

Comment: Have you tried the opposite?  Create a dictionary from file1's words, then iterate over file2?

Comment: Do you mean by "very slow" that the operation takes a long time, or that your machine becomes slow?

Comment: I did try creating a dictionary from file 1 and iterate over file 2. Still slow. By slow, I mean that the operation takes a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if the files are in the same order, and the words in file 1 are are purely a subset of words in file 2:

```
def gen_overlap(file1, file2):
    for word in file1:
        line = file2.read()
        while word not in line:
            line = file2.read()
        yield line
```

If they fail to meet either of those conditions, the best method is to create a `set` of all of the words:

```
gen_overlap(file1, file2):
    word_set = set(line.split() for line in file1)
    for line in file2:
        if line.split()[0] in word_set:
            yield line
```

Comment: No, they're not in the same order and one is not a subset of another.

Comment: The best method then would be to create a `set` of all words in file 1, and check membership of any word in file 2 in that set. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Use this :-

```
def file_comp(a_file,b_file):
    with open(a_file,'r') as file1,open(b_file,'r') as file2:
        read1 = file1.read()
        read2 = file2.read()
        return([i for i in read2.split('\n') if i.split(" ")[0] in read1.split('\n')])
print(file_comp('file_1.txt','file_2.txt'))
```

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: I keep getting this error with  file1.read() -- maybe the file is too large?

Comment: This works for me... You are getting this error because your argument to open file is not correct. Please check the file name or path of the file you are providing. Please let me know in case it still doesn't work with the error you get.

Comment: No, the file name and the path are correct. I solve this problem with the set suggestion above though. Thank you!