# Compare two files and remove the words from the second file Python

Tags: python, file-comparison

I'm trying to compare two files and get the difference using a function.

The first file contains English words - one after the other (engwrds.txt) and the second file is a text file of web scraped text (ws.txt). What I want to achieve is to compare the two files and remove the words from ws.txt and write them to a different file.

In the web scraped file, there are words and sentences. But in the other file, the words are placed one after the other.

I tried the following code but it creates a blank output file.

```
with open('ws.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
    with open('engwrds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('output_file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Then I tried this one, which doesn't print any output at all.

```
from pathlib import Path

with open('engwrds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    exclude = set(line.rstrip() for line in fin)

with fileinput.input('ws.txt', inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not exclude.intersection(Path(line.rstrip()).parts):
            print(line, end='')
```

The following code also doesn't print any output.

```
with open('op11-Copy1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('commonwords.txt', 'r') as file2:
        dif = set(file1).difference(file2)
        
dif.discard('\n')
        
with open('diff.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in dif:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Can you please explain the mistakes I'm making here? I referred multiple examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150875/python-comparing-two-files), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355137/compare-two-file-and-find-matching-words-in-python). But I can't figure out the issue. Ideally, I want to come up with a function that achieves this task.

This is what the ws.txt file looks like.
[image]

This is what the engwrds.txt looks like.
[image]

The output file looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open your files in different variables and compare them.
For Example:

Suppose that the file ws.txt (scraped file) contains:

**your world is beautiful**

And the file engwrds.txt contains these words (one after the other):

**while world want wild**

Open each one in a different variable:

```
with open('engwrds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    engwrds = file.read()

with open('ws.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    ws = file.read()
```

From here **engwrds** and **ws** are **strings**, so you can compare them in many different ways:

```
differences = set(engwrds.split()).symmetric_difference(set(ws.split()))
print(differences)

Output: {'beautiful', 'is', 'want', 'while', 'wild', 'your'}
```

Obviously, this comparison only works if your words are separated by spaces, but from here you will have a better idea of how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you this works. Then I converted this into a function, but it doesn't print line by line. Any thoughts? Here's the function >> def compare_files(f1,f2):
    with open(f1, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
        f1_words = f1.read()
        with open(f2, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
            f2_words = f2.read()
            
            result1 = set(f1_words.split()).symmetric_difference(set(f2_words.split()))
            
            with open('op26.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                file.write(f'{result1}\n\n')

Comment: My idea will not find differences line by line, it just compare both files without keep in mind the order of the lines. So if you need compare line by line, you can workaround of f1_words.split() and f2_words.split() and replace them with f1_words.split("\n") and f2_words.split("\n"). Each of these will give you a list, where each element of the list is a line of your text file. From here, you can compare line by line, but the rest of the problem is all yours (because we don't have your data)

Comment: Sure. I added how the input/output files look like. I want the output of this (op26.txt) also to print line by line.